# Lookup jndi resources WebSphere 8.5, Spring 3.1.3, Hibernate 4.1.10 EJB 3

Tags: spring, hibernate, ejb, websphere, lookup

In my application I need to lookup jndi resources for database connection.

I have an EAR which contain my EJB project with remote and stateless ejb: `ABean.jar`

Reading [Using Spring and Hibernate with WebSphere Application Server](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/0609_alcott/0609_alcott.html) I defined
in the `application.xml` of EAR project:

```
<module>
    <ejb>ABean.jar</ejb>

</module>

<resource-ref>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/b</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>
</resource-ref>
```

In my spring context:

```
<jee:jndi-lookup
    id="aDataSource" 
    jndi-name="jdbc/b" 
    cache="true" 
    expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource"/>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="META-INF/persistence.xml"/>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="aDataSource" />
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="APU"/>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.DB2390Dialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaDialect">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect" />
    </property> 
</bean>
```

Now, if I install application by WebSphere console, it ask to me to assign the jndi resource to `jdbc/b` (and it is ok), but if I try to call an ejb, a `NameNotFoundException` is throw because `jdbc/b` is not found!

Reading better the previous link i see:

> For EJB JAR files, the same resource-ref should be declared in each EJB that needs to access the data source.

so I try to define resource references into my `ejb-jar.xml`

```
<enterprise-beans>
<session>
   <ejb-name>TestServiceBean</ejb-name>
   <ejb-class>it.test.TestServiceBean</ejb-class>
   <session-type>Stateless</session-type>
   <transaction-type>Container</transaction-type>
   <resource-ref>
        <res-ref-name>jdbc/b</res-ref-name>         
        <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>   
   </resource-ref>
 </session>
 </enterprise-beans>
```

I try to install again (I also assign the jndi resource to `jdbc/b`) and the call to the ejb run successfully, but if I have n ejb, do I need to assign n-times the same jndi resource to the n ejb resource-ref for jdbc/b?

What is wrong with my configuration? Isn't it possible "point" to the same `resource-ref` from all ejb? Do you have a complete example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the EE 6 spec, references declared in `application.xml` must be in the `java:app` (or `java:global`) namespaces, and it is recommend that they be in the `env` subcontext, so:

```
<res-ref-name>java:app/env/jdbc/b</res-ref-name>
```

This will allow the resource to be visible to all components in the application.  Alternatively, you can declare a reference in the `java:module` context in ejb-jar.xml or via annotation.

Comment: Can you create an example with my case please?
because if i put java:app/env/ as you said when i try to call an ejb, i have an exception:

Context: NB-025Node01Cell/nodes/NB-025Node01/servers/server1, name: jdbc/b: First component in name b not found. [Root exception is org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextPackage.NotFound: IDL:omg.org/CosNaming/NamingContext/NotFound:1.0]

Comment: Thanks bkail, it works! If I use `<res-ref-name>java:app/env/jdbc/myDs</res-ref-name>` in descriptor and `java:app/env/jdbc/myDs` in the `ctx.lookup()`

Comment: yes it works...simply in the spring configuration i use:

 <jee:jndi-lookup
  id="aDataSource" 
  jndi-name="java:app/env/jdbc/b" 
  cache="true" 
  expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource"/>

Answer (score 0):

Updated answer. Example based on [bkail answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27540908/3701228). You need to define resource reference in `application.xml` like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_6.xsd" version="6">
    <display-name>RefTestEAR</display-name>
    ....
    <resource-ref>
        <res-ref-name>java:app/env/jdbc/b</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    </resource-ref>
</application>
```

Then in your application you can access it via:

```
InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
DataSource datasource = (DataSource) ctx.lookup("java:app/env/jdbc/b");
```

In your case since you are using `Spring` not `InitialContext` directly, you will probably need to change the lookup to and also verify if you have datasource reference in `persistence.xml` (I didn't test that in Spring as I don't have Spring sample at hand):

```
<jee:jndi-lookup
    id="aDataSource" 
    jndi-name="java:app/env/jdbc/b" 
    cache="true" 
    expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource"/>
```