# WebSphere <env-entry> in application.xml and @Resource injection

Tags: java, websphere, jndi, java-ee-6

I can't inject environment entries from *application.xml* using the `@Resource` annotation in my WebSphere 8.5.5 application. (I don't want to move the entry down to the component level *ejb-jar.xml*.) What am I missing?

application.xml:

```
<application
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_6.xsd"
        version="6">

    <env-entry>
        <env-entry-name>fileName</env-entry-name>
        <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
        <env-entry-value>theValue</env-entry-value>
    </env-entry>
```

With this, I **do** see "fileName" defined as "theValue" in the WebSphere Admin Console section *Environment entries for the application*. Yet I can't figure out how to access this from my EJB.

StartupBean.java:

```
@Singleton
@Startup
public class StartupBean {
    @Resource(name = "fileName")
    private String fileName = "default";
```

`fileName` is always "default", not "theValue".

I tried a manual lookup using both "java:comp" and "java:app" (as suggested by [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44325513/687315)), but both throw `NamingException`

```
Context ctx = new InitialContext();
fileName = (String) ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/fileName");
fileName = (String) ctx.lookup("java:app/env/fileName");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resources declared in `application.xml` must use either the `java:app/env` or `java:global/env` prefix, so it should look like:

```
<env-entry>
    <env-entry-name>java:app/env/fileName</env-entry-name>
    <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
    <env-entry-value>theValue</env-entry-value>
</env-entry>
```

Then, injection into the field would be as follows:

```
@Resource(name = "java:app/env/fileName")
private String fileName = "default";
```